# Is it possible to restart XBee with command when power on?

Tags: xbee

I am using XBee S2 ZigBee to do wireless communication, but sometimes I met cases that XBee failed to get some data frame and after several rounds it stopped. I found out that after I power off both XBees and then power on again, it will work again. So I guess if I can restart it with command when power on, I might able to make it work continuously.

I am using the python-xbee library to send out and receive data.

The xbee connected to computer side was set to API mode as coordinator; the xbee connected to sensor board was set to AT mode as router.

Is it possible to restart both of them with command when power on? How?

Comment: Almost every digital IC has an external reset that can be toggled by bringing the voltage low or high, you should be able to use the same circuit for both, it may take some hacking

Comment: @laptop2d I guess this is the only way to solve my problem now. Even though not as I expected, but it should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this document (and others) : https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/pdfs/90002002.pdf there is no command to reboot the module.
But a litle trick you can try, is to use one of the GPIO of your module to do a hard reset of your module like so :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMnytt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But of course the best way is to find what causes the errors !

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the only way I can use to solve the problem. I read the document for several times but cannot figure out a good way solving my problem. And you are right about finding what causes the errors. Thanks.